# How to download a copy of the html from a website?

Tags: php, mysql, curl, file-get-contents

How do I download a copy of the html from a website that has language detection (eg google, youtube) and redirection? I have tried file_get_contents but it is to limited.

I am trying to use curl in php to get the html from www.google.com but it detects that I am from the UK and sends me a 302 redirect to www.google.co.uk.

I have tried many different things with no joy, is this possible? websites like www.markosweb.com do it..

my code:

```
$ch  = curl_init( "http://www.google.com/" );    

// $userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)";
//  $userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

$userAgent = 'Googlebot/2.1 (http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)';


$header = array(
         "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5",
         "Accept-Language: en-US,us;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
         "Accept-Charset: windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
         "Keep-Alive: 300");

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE); //TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5); //The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect. 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent); //The contents of the "User-Agent: " header to be used in a HTTP request.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE); //To fail silently if the HTTP code returned is greater than or equal to 400.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); //To follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE); //To automatically set the Referer: field in requests where it follows a Location: redirect.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); //The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 0);

$content = curl_exec( $ch );    
$err     = curl_errno( $ch );    
$errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );    
$header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );    
curl_close( $ch );    
$header['errno']   = $err;    
$header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;    
$header['content'] = $content;    
return $header;
```

I have tried changing the useragent to lots of things, tried with and without header details. I managed to get something if I used header info : "Accept-Language: ru-ru,ru;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3" but it was in russian or something.

Thanks for your help.
Carl

Comment: @DumbProducts The link on that website is spam and redirects me to some asian website...

Comment: Ah yes your right. Sorry bout that. :}

Answer (score 1):

Try this proxy script:

```
// Change these configuration options if needed, see above descriptions for info.
$enable_jsonp    = false;
$enable_native   = false;
$valid_url_regex = '/.*/';

// ############################################################################

$url = $_GET['url'];

if ( !$url ) {

  // Passed url not specified.
  $contents = 'ERROR: url not specified';
  $status = array( 'http_code' => 'ERROR' );

} else if ( !preg_match( $valid_url_regex, $url ) ) {

  // Passed url doesn't match $valid_url_regex.
  $contents = 'ERROR: invalid url';
  $status = array( 'http_code' => 'ERROR' );

} else {
  $ch = curl_init( $url );

  if ( strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'post' ) {
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST );
  }

  if ( $_GET['send_cookies'] ) {
    $cookie = array();
    foreach ( $_COOKIE as $key => $value ) {
      $cookie[] = $key . '=' . $value;
    }
    if ( $_GET['send_session'] ) {
      $cookie[] = SID;
    }
    $cookie = implode( '; ', $cookie );

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie );
  }

  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_GET['user_agent'] ? $_GET['user_agent'] : $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );

  list( $header, $contents ) = preg_split( '/([\r\n][\r\n])\\1/', curl_exec( $ch ), 2 );

  $status = curl_getinfo( $ch );

  curl_close( $ch );
}

// Split header text into an array.
$header_text = preg_split( '/[\r\n]+/', $header );

if ( $_GET['mode'] == 'native' ) {
  if ( !$enable_native ) {
    $contents = 'ERROR: invalid mode';
    $status = array( 'http_code' => 'ERROR' );
  }

  // Propagate headers to response.
  foreach ( $header_text as $header ) {
    if ( preg_match( '/^(?:Content-Type|Content-Language|Set-Cookie):/i', $header ) ) {
      header( $header );
    }
  }

  print $contents;

} else {

  // $data will be serialized into JSON data.
  $data = array();

  // Propagate all HTTP headers into the JSON data object.
  if ( $_GET['full_headers'] ) {
    $data['headers'] = array();

    foreach ( $header_text as $header ) {
      preg_match( '/^(.+?):\s+(.*)$/', $header, $matches );
      if ( $matches ) {
        $data['headers'][ $matches[1] ] = $matches[2];
      }
    }
  }

  // Propagate all cURL request / response info to the JSON data object.
  if ( $_GET['full_status'] ) {
    $data['status'] = $status;
  } else {
    $data['status'] = array();
    $data['status']['http_code'] = $status['http_code'];
  }

  // Set the JSON data object contents, decoding it from JSON if possible.
  $decoded_json = json_decode( $contents );
  $data['contents'] = $decoded_json ? $decoded_json : $contents;

  // Generate appropriate content-type header.
  $is_xhr = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
  header( 'Content-type: application/' . ( $is_xhr ? 'json' : 'x-javascript' ) );

  // Get JSONP callback.
  $jsonp_callback = $enable_jsonp && isset($_GET['callback']) ? $_GET['callback'] : null;

  // Generate JSON/JSONP string
  $json = json_encode( $data );

  print $jsonp_callback ? "$jsonp_callback($json)" : $json;

}
```

Make sure to perform a request like this:
http://example.com/script?url=http://whateverurl.com/

Oh, and this PHP script will display the result in JSON.
From there, you can parse it using jQuery.

Like I use this jQuery code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var url='+++++URL WHICH THE PHP PROXY SCRIPT IS IN++++++';
$(window).load(function(){
        $.getJSON(url,function(json){
               $("#resu").append(""+json.contents+"");
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**Edit:** This script is not a true proxy in the sense that it does fake an IP address. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks but if I use a Proxy then Google will detect that I am from (whereever the proxy is based say US) which will be fine for google.com but then I will have the same problem when trying to get the html from google.co.uk. I want to be able to collect data from every tld for every website (eg .co.uk, .com .jp, .net etc) Carl

Comment: @Calos Not necessarily. You can set the script to utilize a specific IP address (which could be like in the UK). Here's where I got the script from: http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/ . There's quite a bit of documentation.

Comment: @Calos That's incorrect. It can be accomplished in PHP, as proven in the code example in my post. Just visit the project link I gave you, and click on "Simple Proxy PHP". Here's the project link: http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/ and here's the PHP code (some of it's also in my post): http://benalman.com/code/projects/php-simple-proxy/examples/simple/

Comment: I cant see what that code does different to my code? Please explain which part of the code uses the PROXY? Carl

Comment: @Calos It is a proxy, but I just realized that they'res no way to set the IP... :} You're right, it uses the IP of the server...

Comment: Yes! Thanks for all your input! I would need a proxy server for each country/tld. Hmmm comlplcated me thinks!

Comment: @Calos sorry about that... Try http://freshmeat.net/projects/phpproxy/, or perhaps http://code.google.com/p/php-web-proxy/.

Comment: @Calos This script seems to work the best, and you can feed the country/tld which it should proxy on the basis of: https://github.com/Alexxz/Simple-php-proxy-script . Another one is http://www.mediafire.com/?6c66ciw1t7zbz0w